# How to find all WPF controls definition and usage examples?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

Where can I find a reference for definitions and examples of all WPF controls. I'm new to WPF and much confused with the usage of majority of controls (such as canvas, stackpanel, winformshost, wrappanel, dockpanel, contentconstrol.) In WinForms, we didn't have that many controls. Googled for wpf control definitions and usage, but found nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start here:  [Windows Presentation Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en/library/ms754130.aspx) for general WPF information.

For info specifically on controls:   [Controls by Category](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754204.aspx)

The msdn site is probably your first best option to find out about WPF.

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN Control Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752324.aspx) is always a good start.

I also found [this](http://www.wpftutorial.net/) site useful when I began using WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit the link

http://wpftutorial.net/Layout.html

Here you will find the code samples as well as the explanation.